Alignment of mat-icon-button and mat-button
I have a scenario where I want to align some buttons on the same horizontal line. I cannot understand why the mat-icon-button does not have the same alignment as the rest of the buttons. Both have default height of 48px, but still it looks like this.
I know that I can align this with Bootstrap, but then it comes with other problem. I will have more input with mat-chips to the left of the buttons. There will be a dynamic amount of them, which will cause multiple rows and the chips, mat-flat-button and mat-icon-button on each row should be aligned.

Why is this the default behaviour? What is a feasible workaround?

please share code and not screenshots, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated for checking it!

@NarenMurali Yes, sure. Just a fork from the Angular materials button component where I have removed the unnecessary around it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/e6ajny?file=src%2Fexample%2Fbutton-overview-example.html

Just add display: flex;align-items: center; to your parent div style

The mat-icon-button is by default bigger than the other buttons, you can use the below CSS to adjust it!
::ng-deep .normal-sized-button {
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  vertical-align: bottom !important;
  height: 36px !important;
  width: 36px !important;
}
::ng-deep .normal-sized-button mat-icon {
  position: absolute !important;
  left: calc(50% - 12px) !important;
  top: calc(50% - 12px) !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo

Just add vertical-align: bottom to fix the issue!
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  <button mat-flat-button>Basic</button>

  <button mat-flat-button color="warn">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>

  <button mat-icon-button style="border: 1px solid black;vertical-align: bottom;">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you! This works when using the new M2 styling However, if I just change back to the default theming (which my project use), it is still problems as the buttons have different heights. Isn't this a strange behaviour of the design? Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/e6ajny-nphjpj?file=src%2Fexample%2Fbutton-overview-example.html

@mr3k but it still seems to work stackblitz

Not really as the buttons have different heights which will cause additional spacing between rows

@mr3k is this the expected output stackblitz

Yes, more like it. So css is needed or going to the new M2/M3 styling?

@mr3k the button is inherently larger than the other buttons, I doubt the styling matters, if you have a problem for a particular scenario, just scope the CSS using a class and customize it to your requirements! but if you switch between M2/M3 you might need to adjust the CSS slightly!
